# Не создаются значения в реестре

Tags: c++, qt, реестр

У меня есть два QSettings в разных файлах, у одного все значения передаются в реестр, а другого - нет

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSettings>
#include "counter2.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow* ui;
    counter2*       counter_2;
    counter2*       counter_3;
    QSettings*      settings;

public:
    void save();
    void load();

private slots:
        //Diclaration slots'
    void cleanLines();
    void cleanAmounters();
    void cleanAll();

    void toggleCounter3();
    void toggleCounter4();
    void toggleCounter5();
    void toggleCounter6();
    void toggleWindow2();
    void toggleWindow3();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp:** //здесь всё ок

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "counter2.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    counter_2 = new counter2();
    counter_3 = new counter2();
    settings  = new QSettings("SimpleStudio", "Counter1", this);

    //Diclaration variables & QObject::connect

    connect(counter_2, &counter2::toggleToCounter1,
            this,      &MainWindow::show);

    connect(counter_3, &counter2::toggleToCounter1,
            this,      &MainWindow::show);

    connect(counter_3, &counter2::toggleToCounter2,
            this,      &MainWindow::toggleWindow2);

    connect(counter_2, &counter2::toggleToCounter3,
            this,      &MainWindow::toggleWindow3);

    QObject::connect(ui->toggleButton2, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                      this,     SLOT(toggleWindow2()));

    QObject::connect(ui->toggleButton3, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                      this,     SLOT(toggleWindow3()));

    QObject::connect(ui->cleanLines, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,           SLOT(cleanLines()));

    QObject::connect(ui->cleanAmounts, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,             SLOT(cleanAmounters()));

    QObject::connect(ui->cleanAll, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,         SLOT(cleanAll()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox3, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter3()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox4, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter4()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox5, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter5()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox6, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter6()));

    load();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    save();
}
//Discription slots'
void MainWindow::save() {

    settings->setValue("nameCounterTop", ui->nameCounterTop->text());

    settings->setValue("nameCounter1", ui->nameCounter1->text());
    settings->setValue("nameCounter2", ui->nameCounter2->text());
    settings->setValue("nameCounter3", ui->nameCounter3->text());
    settings->setValue("nameCounter4", ui->nameCounter4->text());
    settings->setValue("nameCounter5", ui->nameCounter5->text());
    settings->setValue("nameCounter6", ui->nameCounter6->text());

    settings->setValue("valueCounter1", ui->amounter1->value());
    settings->setValue("valueCounter2", ui->amounter2->value());
    settings->setValue("valueCounter3", ui->amounter3->value());
    settings->setValue("valueCounter4", ui->amounter4->value());
    settings->setValue("valueCounter5", ui->amounter5->value());
    settings->setValue("valueCounter6", ui->amounter6->value());

}

void MainWindow::load() {

    ui->nameCounterTop->setText(settings->value("nameCounterTop").toString());

    ui->nameCounter1->setText(settings->value("nameCounter1").toString());
    ui->nameCounter2->setText(settings->value("nameCounter2").toString());
    ui->nameCounter3->setText(settings->value("nameCounter3").toString());
    ui->nameCounter4->setText(settings->value("nameCounter4").toString());
    ui->nameCounter5->setText(settings->value("nameCounter5").toString());
    ui->nameCounter6->setText(settings->value("nameCounter6").toString());

    ui->amounter1->setValue(settings->value("valueCounter1").toInt());
    ui->amounter2->setValue(settings->value("valueCounter2").toInt());
    ui->amounter3->setValue(settings->value("valueCounter3").toInt());
    ui->amounter4->setValue(settings->value("valueCounter4").toInt());
    ui->amounter5->setValue(settings->value("valueCounter5").toInt());
    ui->amounter6->setValue(settings->value("valueCounter6").toInt());
}

void MainWindow::cleanLines() {

    ui->nameCounter1->clear();
    ui->nameCounter2->clear();
    ui->nameCounter3->clear();
    ui->nameCounter4->clear();
    ui->nameCounter5->clear();
    ui->nameCounter6->clear();

}

void MainWindow::cleanAmounters() {

    ui->amounter1->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter2->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter3->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter4->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter5->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter6->setValue(0);

}

void MainWindow::cleanAll() {

    ui->nameCounterTop->clear();

    ui->checkBox3->setChecked(0);
    emit MainWindow::toggleCounter3();

    ui->checkBox4->setChecked(0);
    emit MainWindow::toggleCounter4();

    ui->checkBox5->setChecked(0);
    emit MainWindow::toggleCounter5();

    ui->checkBox6->setChecked(0);
    emit MainWindow::toggleCounter6();

    emit MainWindow::cleanLines();
    emit MainWindow::cleanAmounters();
}

void MainWindow::toggleCounter3(){

    if(!ui->checkBox3->isChecked()) {

        ui->amounter3->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter3->setEnabled(0);

    } else {

        ui->amounter3->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter3->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void MainWindow::toggleCounter4(){

    if(!ui->checkBox4->isChecked()) {

        ui->amounter4->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter4->setEnabled(0);

    } else {

        ui->amounter4->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter4->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void MainWindow::toggleCounter5(){

    if(!ui->checkBox5->isChecked()) {
        ui->amounter5->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter5->setEnabled(0);

    } else {
        ui->amounter5->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter5->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void MainWindow::toggleCounter6(){

    if(!ui->checkBox6->isChecked()) {
        ui->amounter6->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter6->setEnabled(0);

    } else {
        ui->amounter6->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter6->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void MainWindow::toggleWindow2() {
        counter_2->show();
        this->close();
}

void MainWindow::toggleWindow3() {
        counter_3->show();
        this->close();    
}
```

**counter2.h:**

```
#ifndef COUNTER2_H
#define COUNTER2_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets>

namespace Ui {class counter2;}

class counter2 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit counter2(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~counter2();



signals :
    void toggleToCounter1();
    void toggleToCounter2();
    void toggleToCounter3();

private:
    Ui::counter2 *ui;
    counter2*   counter_2;
    counter2*   counter_3;
    QSettings*  settings1;

public:
    void save();
    void load();

private slots:
    void toggleWindow1();
    void toggleWindow2();
    void toggleWindow3();

    void cleanLines();
    void cleanAmounters();
    void cleanAll();

    void toggleCounter3();
    void toggleCounter4();
    void toggleCounter5();
    void toggleCounter6();     
};

#endif // COUNTER2_H
```

**counter2.cpp:** //здесь не всё ок((

```
#include "counter2.h"
#include "ui_counter2.h"

counter2::counter2(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::counter2)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    settings1 = new QSettings("SimpleStudio", "Counter2", this);
    //Diclaration variables & QObject::connect

    connect(ui->toggleButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            this, SLOT(toggleWindow1()));

    connect(ui->toggleButton2, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            this, SLOT(toggleWindow2()));

    connect(ui->toggleButton3, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            this, SLOT(toggleWindow3()));

    QObject::connect(ui->cleanLines, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,           SLOT(cleanLines()));

    QObject::connect(ui->cleanAmounts, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,             SLOT(cleanAmounters()));

    QObject::connect(ui->cleanAll, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,         SLOT(cleanAll()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox3, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter3()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox4, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter4()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox5, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter5()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox6, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter6()));

    counter2::load();
}

counter2::~counter2()
{
    delete ui;
    counter2::save();
}
//Discription slots'
void counter2::save()
{
    settings1->setValue("nameCounterTop", ui->nameCounterTop->text());

    settings1->setValue("nameCounter1", ui->nameCounter1->text());
    settings1->setValue("nameCounter2", ui->nameCounter2->text());
    settings1->setValue("nameCounter3", ui->nameCounter3->text());
    settings1->setValue("nameCounter4", ui->nameCounter4->text());
    settings1->setValue("nameCounter5", ui->nameCounter5->text());
    settings1->setValue("nameCounter6", ui->nameCounter6->text());

    settings1->setValue("valueCounter1", ui->amounter1->value());
    settings1->setValue("valueCounter2", ui->amounter2->value());
    settings1->setValue("valueCounter3", ui->amounter3->value());
    settings1->setValue("valueCounter4", ui->amounter4->value());
    settings1->setValue("valueCounter5", ui->amounter5->value());
    settings1->setValue("valueCounter6", ui->amounter6->value());
}

void counter2::load()
{
    ui->nameCounterTop->setText(settings1->value("nameCounterTop").toString());

    ui->nameCounter1->setText(settings1->value("nameCounter1").toString());
    ui->nameCounter2->setText(settings1->value("nameCounter2").toString());
    ui->nameCounter3->setText(settings1->value("nameCounter3").toString());
    ui->nameCounter4->setText(settings1->value("nameCounter4").toString());
    ui->nameCounter5->setText(settings1->value("nameCounter5").toString());
    ui->nameCounter6->setText(settings1->value("nameCounter6").toString());

    ui->amounter1->setValue(settings1->value("valueCounter1").toInt());
    ui->amounter2->setValue(settings1->value("valueCounter2").toInt());
    ui->amounter3->setValue(settings1->value("valueCounter3").toInt());
    ui->amounter4->setValue(settings1->value("valueCounter4").toInt());
    ui->amounter5->setValue(settings1->value("valueCounter5").toInt());
    ui->amounter6->setValue(settings1->value("valueCounter6").toInt());
}

void counter2::cleanLines() {

    ui->nameCounter1->clear();
    ui->nameCounter2->clear();
    ui->nameCounter3->clear();
    ui->nameCounter4->clear();
    ui->nameCounter5->clear();
    ui->nameCounter6->clear();

}

void counter2::cleanAmounters() {

    ui->amounter1->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter2->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter3->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter4->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter5->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter6->setValue(0);

}

void counter2::cleanAll() {

    ui->nameCounterTop->clear();

    ui->checkBox3->setChecked(0);
    emit counter2::toggleCounter3();

    ui->checkBox4->setChecked(0);
    emit counter2::toggleCounter4();

    ui->checkBox5->setChecked(0);
    emit counter2::toggleCounter5();

    ui->checkBox6->setChecked(0);
    emit counter2::toggleCounter6();

    emit counter2::cleanLines();
    emit counter2::cleanAmounters();
}

void counter2::toggleCounter3(){

    if(!ui->checkBox3->isChecked()) {

        ui->amounter3->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter3->setEnabled(0);

    } else {

        ui->amounter3->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter3->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void counter2::toggleCounter4(){

    if(!ui->checkBox4->isChecked()) {

        ui->amounter4->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter4->setEnabled(0);

    } else {

        ui->amounter4->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter4->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void counter2::toggleCounter5(){

    if(!ui->checkBox5->isChecked()) {
        ui->amounter5->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter5->setEnabled(0);

    } else {
        ui->amounter5->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter5->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void counter2::toggleCounter6(){

    if(!ui->checkBox6->isChecked()) {
        ui->amounter6->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter6->setEnabled(0);

    } else {
        ui->amounter6->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter6->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter6->setCursorPosition(int());
    }
}

void counter2::toggleWindow1() {

    emit toggleToCounter1();
    this->close();
}

void counter2::toggleWindow2() {

    emit toggleToCounter2();
    this->close();
}

void counter2::toggleWindow3() {

    emit toggleToCounter3();
    this->close();
}
```

В папке counter1 есть файлы со значениями, а в counter2 - нету

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
delete ui;
counter2::save();
```

Вы сначала удаляете гуй, а потом в функции `counter2::save` вы обращаетесь к ui `settings1->setValue("nameCounterTop", ui->nameCounterTop->text());`
**В обоих случаях это ошибка**
Правильно сначала сохранить все значения, а потом удалить гуй, вот так:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    save();
    delete ui;
}

counter2::~counter2()
{
    save();
    delete ui; 
}
```

2) объекты класса `counter2` создаются динамически (через new), что значит, что их надо удалять вручную, иначе будет утечка памяти (память была веделена, но не освобождена).
На данный момент у вас объекты counter_2 и counter_2 нигде не удаляются, что значит и деструктор класса `counter2` не вызывается и в реестр ничего не пишется.
Перепишите деструктор следующим образом:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    save(); // Вызываем сохранение MainWindow
    delete counter_2; // удаляем counter_2, что вызовет сохранение
    delete counter_3; // удаляем counter_3, аналогично
    delete settings; // удаляем settings, т.к. он тоже создан динамически
    delete ui; // удаляем гуй, т.к. он больше не нужен        
}
```

**UPD:**
Чтобы значения сохранялись для обоих счетчиков их надо как-то отделить друг от друга, проще всего это сделать с помощью дополнительного текстового поля:

```
class counter2 : public QWidget
{
...
public:
    explicit counter2(const QString& registry, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
...
private:
    QString m_registry;
...
}
```

Конструктор переделаем так:

```
counter2::counter2(const QString& registry, QWidget *parent /*= nullptr*/) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::counter2),
    m_registry(registry)
{
...
    settings1 = new QSettings("SimpleStudio", m_registry, this); // теперь каждый счетчик будет записываться согласно значению m_registry
...
}
```

А в главном окне нам надо задать уникальные имена для счетчиков

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    counter_2 = new counter2("Counter2");
    counter_3 = new counter2("Counter3");
...
```

Теперь каждый счетчик будет записываться в свою ветку регистра

Comment: Всё начало работать! Но если вы заметили, то у меня два счётчика... как сделать, чтобы они отдельно сохраняли значения, и для counter_2 и для counter_3?

Comment: @Pon4iPay смотрите UPD в ответе)